# is it possible to run meteor with mongoDB on Maverics 10.9.5?

Tags: meteor

I'm running OsX 10.9.5 and React 16. After meteor installation fallowed by instruction from site https://www.meteor.com/install, installation process goes without any problems.
When I'm trying run meteor from terminal `meteor run` I get this:

```
[[[[[ ~/Codding/cdbioffice ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
dyld: Symbol not found: _fchmodat
Referenced from:
/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in
/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
dyld: Symbol not found: _fchmodat
Referenced from:
/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in
/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
dyld: Symbol not found: _fchmodat
Referenced from:
/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in
/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server
```

In VisualStudio from project directory after `meteor npm start` in terminal I get additional info:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 254
npm ERR! cd-bioffice-meteor@ start: `meteor run --settings settings.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 254
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cd-bioffice-meteor@ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/lukasz/.npm/_logs/2019-01-14T13_48_22_707Z-debug.log
```

and in log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.11.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle cd-bioffice-meteor@~prestart: cd-bioffice-meteor@
6 info lifecycle cd-bioffice-meteor@~start: cd-bioffice-meteor@
7 verbose lifecycle cd-bioffice-meteor@~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle cd-bioffice-meteor@~start: PATH: /Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/lukasz/Codding/cdbioffice/node_modules/.bin:/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin:/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64:/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/.bin:/Users/lukasz/.npm-global/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/lukasz/.npm-global/bin
9 verbose lifecycle cd-bioffice-meteor@~start: CWD: /Users/lukasz/Codding/cdbioffice
10 silly lifecycle cd-bioffice-meteor@~start: Args: [ '-c', 'meteor run --settings settings.json' ]
11 silly lifecycle cd-bioffice-meteor@~start: Returned: code: 254  signal: null
12 info lifecycle cd-bioffice-meteor@~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: cd-bioffice-meteor@ start: `meteor run --settings settings.json`
13 verbose stack Exit status 254
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid cd-bioffice-meteor@
15 verbose cwd /Users/lukasz/Codding/cdbioffice
16 verbose Darwin 13.4.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node" "/Users/lukasz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v8.11.4
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 254
22 error cd-bioffice-meteor@ start: `meteor run --settings settings.json`
22 error Exit status 254
23 error Failed at the cd-bioffice-meteor@ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 254, true ]
```

What I'm doing wrong? I found bunch of answer on this topic but I'm not sure witch direction should I go. One of them is that OsX 10.9 is to old to run that config. I don't want to make this situation worst.

System:
Maverics 10.9.5
node -v && npm -v
v9.5.0
5.6.0

Thanks for your help.

package.json for existing project (I'm interested on):

```
{
  "name": "cd-bioffice-meteor",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run --settings settings.json",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "test-app": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "visualize": "meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "npm": "^6.5.0",
    "polished": "^2.0.3",
    "react": "^16.5.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
    "react-inlinesvg": "^0.8.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "serialport": "^7.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^3.4.6"
  },
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/main.jsx",
      "server": "server/main.js"
    },
    "testModule": "tests/main.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run a new created project using `meteor create projectname` or an existing project you checked out?

Comment: this is an existing project, bot I've checeked with new one and is this same story. Is it posible to have different version of node and npm? _(from command line I heve node -v && npm -v v9.5.0 5.6.0, and from error log - 2 info using npm@6.4.1     3 info using node@v8.11.4)_

Comment: With Meteor you have a bundled npm and node, which are accessible through `meteor node` and `meteor npm`. For example: if you install your npm packages you don't run `npm install` but always `meteor npm install`. Also you don't need to use `meteor run` but can just use `meteor` to start the app. Please add your `package.json` file to the question using the `edit` button.

Comment: I just added ```package.json``` for existing project

Comment: meteor rel.1.6 is running on OsX 10.9.5